# Are these nested loops? Java

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

Is this code showing nested loops or just a lot of loops after each other? They are all inside of the first loop, but not inside each other. Is this a good practice or not?

```
    for (int outputDigits = STARTING_NUMBER; outputDigits <= MAX_NUMBER; outputDigits = outputDigits + 2) {  // controls number output

        for (int innerDashes = dashIncrement; innerDashes <= DASHES; innerDashes++) {      // inner dashes
            System.out.print("-");
        }


            for (int digits = 1; digits <= outputDigits; digits++) {           // prints the number x amount of times
                System.out.print(outputDigits);
            }


                for (int outerDashes = dashIncrement; outerDashes <= DASHES; outerDashes++) {  // outer dashes
                    System.out.print("-");
                }
        System.out.println();
        dashIncrement++;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a combination of both a nested loops as well as loops after each other. The code does not look easily readable. Better way would have been to have a private function called printCharacters which takes your dash character as input and the times it needs to be printed

```
private void printString(String inputString, int count) {
for (int i=0;i<=count;i++ {
System.out.print(inputString);
```

}
}

```
for (int outputDigits = STARTING_NUMBER; outputDigits <= MAX_NUMBER; outputDigits = outputDigits + 2) {  // controls number output

   printString("-",DASHES-dashIncrement);

        for (int digits = 1; digits <= outputDigits; digits++) {           // prints the number x amount of times
            System.out.print(outputDigits);
        }


           printString("-",DASHES-dashIncrement);
    System.out.println();
    dashIncrement++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's the question here. There are clearly nested loops here, as well as a number of successive loops one after the other. Good practice? Yes it's perfectly alright to do this if the problem you're trying to solve demands it. Nothing wrong with using nested loops; In fact they are required in many,many algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You're confused due to improper indentation. The inner three for-loops(innerDashes, digits, and outerDashes) are all nested inside the outer for-loop(outputDigits) and should be at the same indentation. There is only one level of nesting here. All the three inner loops are at the same nesting level.

Also, I would suggest not to use braces{} for for-loops that only contain one statement that needs to be looped.

Comment: Au contraire, I would suggest using braces always. It's clearer and lack of braces can cause subtle bugs, such as accidentally putting a ';' at the end of the for statement. Also if you need to add additional statements inside the loop, the braces are already there.

Comment: I guess you're right in those regards. But I always found single-statement for-loops without braces to be more cleaner. Maybe it's a personal choice.

Comment: I do/did too, but I noticed that it's quite rare that they'll stay as single-statement-loops, that I started to add the braces. It really depends on what sort of code is happening around it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have a couple of loops nested inside another loop.

As to whether it's good practice, it depends. Does it make sense? There are no universal truths in programming (well, barring a few), so you can't learn rules like "don't use nested loops".

Although looking at your code, it would indeed be more legible to use the "extract method" refactoring to turn the dash printing for loops into a separate method.

Answer (score 0):

Nested loops are something like this :

```
for(...){
    for(...){
         // Your code comes here.
    }
}
```

Loop within a loop is called nested Loop. Your code fulfill this statement so yes, that is nested loop's example.